# menu is not active after clicking the link..(after page loads)

Tags: javascript, jquery

finally i did this by following javascript..

```
  function extractPageName(hrefString)
{
    var arr = hrefString.split('/');
    return  (arr.length<2) ? hrefString : arr[arr.length-2].toLowerCase() + arr[arr.length-1].toLowerCase();               
}

function setActiveMenu(arr, crtPage)
{
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(extractPageName(arr[i].href) == crtPage)
        {
            if (arr[i].parentNode.tagName != "DIV")
            {
                arr[i].className = "selected";
                arr[i].parentNode.className = "selected";
            }
        }
    }
}

function setPage()
{
    hrefString = document.location.href ? document.location.href : document.location;

    if (document.getElementById("but_a")!=null)
        setActiveMenu(document.getElementById("but_a").getElementsByTagName("a"), extractPageName(hrefString));
}
```

if i click the ul without clicking the link.. its working.. when i click the link. it works until the page loads. after the page load, the ul back groud going default class not "selected" class..am new to tis.. am struggling so hard.. need help..??

I've added a jdFiddle with an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Suren/u4szQ/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a.button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    });
  });
```

You've got too much javascript there.

After your posted fiddle. [Here is a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/u4szQ/3/)
Note you have a great deal of malformed HTML. You can't place divs in between list items. You can't have multiple objects on a page with the same ID (use a class instead).

Comment: it doesnt work.. if removeClass is omitted, then if i click next tab, the previous tab is also active..

Comment: No offense, but that code is all sorts of mess. See edit in my answer with updated fiddle.

Comment: You need to add a class on page load. The javascript will not carry through page loads. Set the selected class for the navigation on that page in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on anchor the page is going to navigate to the url set on anchor's `href` attribute so whatever javascript operation you do is going to be lost after the page is loaded.

If you want to highlight the selected link the you can probably send the link id or some identifier along with the url and then check for it on page load and set the appropriate link selected.

By the way `toggleClass` adds or removes one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.